# sencha, Grid not update automatically when a store is updated

Tags: gridview, extjs, data-binding, datastore, extjs6-modern

Well consider the following test code, written in extjs 6.5 modern.

```
 Ext.define('myApp.store.Sections', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
     storeId: 'Sections',
     alias: 'store.sections',

     fields: ['name', 'event'],

     data: {
         items: [{
             name: 'blah',
             event: 'a'
         }, {
             name: 'hello',
             event: 'a'
         }, {
             name: 'world',
             event: 'a'
         }, {
             name: 'foo',
             event: 'b'
         }, {
             name: 'bar',
             event: 'b'
         }]
     },

     proxy: {
         type: 'memory',
         reader: {
             type: 'json',
             rootProperty: 'items'
         }
     }
 });
 Ext.create({
     xtype: 'container',
     title: 'Panel Title',
     iconCls: 'x-fa fa-html5',
     height: 400,
     width: 400,
     fullscreen: true,

     layout: {
         type: 'vbox',
         align: 'stretch'
     },
     items: [{
         xtype: 'grid',
         name: 'master',
         store: {
             type: 'sections',
         },
         layout: 'fit',
         flex: 1,
         plugins: {
             gridcellediting: {
                 selectOnEdit: true,
                 triggerEvent: 'tap',
             }
         },
         columns: [{
             text: 'name',
             dataIndex: 'name',
             flex: 1,
             editor: {
                 xtype: 'textfield',
             }
         }]
     }, {
         xtype: 'grid',
         name: 'firstslave',
         store: {
             type: 'sections',
         },
         layout: 'fit',
         flex: 1,
         columns: [{
             text: 'name',
             dataIndex: 'name',
             flex: 1
         }]
     }, {
         xtype: 'combobox',
         name: 'secondslave',
         displayField: 'name',
         valueField: 'name',
         store: {
             type: 'sections'
         }
     }]
 });
```

One can modify the store entries through the first grid. If the store is modified this way, the changes are visible inside the combobox (second slave).

However the second grid doesn't reflect those changes, there the items stay the same and thus the gridview is out of sync with the underlying data.

Why does this happen? Can this be prevented?

EDIT: I've noticed that if I reorder the grid (by means of the column menu) the items are updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using [`store`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.data.Store.html) for you all component

```js
store: {
  type: 'sections'
}
```

So in that case every component have new instance of your `sections` store. That's why your changes is not reflecting.

---

You can achieve your required result by using 2 way

1. By using [`ViewModel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html) and `binding` config
2. You can directly assign the storeId to your component

   ```
   store:'sections' //In that case you store should be created
   ```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2jl8)**, I have create demo using `ViewModel` and `binding`.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.define('myApp.store.Sections', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            storeId: 'Sections',
            alias: 'store.sections',

            fields: ['name', 'event'],

            data: {
                items: [{
                    name: 'blah',
                    event: 'a'
                }, {
                    name: 'hello',
                    event: 'a'
                }, {
                    name: 'world',
                    event: 'a'
                }, {
                    name: 'foo',
                    event: 'b'
                }, {
                    name: 'bar',
                    event: 'b'
                }]
            },

            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'items'
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.define('MainModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

            alias: 'viewmodel.main',

            stores: {
                myStore: {
                    type: 'sections'
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Panel Title',
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-html5',
            //height: 400,
            fullscreen: true,

            viewModel: {
                type: 'main'
            },

            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',
                title: 'Grid 1',
                name: 'master',
                bind: '{myStore}',
                layout: 'fit',
                flex: 1,
                plugins: {
                    gridcellediting: {
                        selectOnEdit: true,
                        triggerEvent: 'tap'
                    }
                },
                columns: [{
                    text: 'name',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    flex: 1,
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield'
                    }

                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'grid',
                title: 'Grid 2',
                name: 'firstslave',
                bind: '{myStore}',
                layout: 'fit',
                flex: 1,
                columns: [{
                    text: 'name',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    flex: 1
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Combo panel',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    name: 'secondslave',
                    displayField: 'name',
                    valueField: 'name',
                    bind: {
                        store: '{myStore}'
                    },
                    margin:'0 0 30 0'
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this (`viewmodel: { type: x }}`) also mean that each component has its own viewmodel? And thus its own copy of the store?

Comment: `viewmodel: { type: x }}` this just type of defining the view model to your component. it is not creating new instance. viewmodel is concept change once place and reflection throughout your application where you have used

Comment: And I have already mentioned another way by providing store id you can also use that.

Comment: Oh I'm not saying the solution is bad, I'm just trying to understand why `store: {type: x} creates a new store for each component, yet the same syntax doesn't do that for each viewmodel.

Comment: no man this way to define the viewmodel. but for store you have two way to assign the by alias or by store id